# How to get the position in a checkbox inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I have a listView with a checkbox. That I want to do is when I click the checkBox show in a Toast the position of this checkbox. I'm trying some things but I don't now what I'm doing wrong. I find some similars solutions here but doesn't work for me.

In my code I can show the Toast if you press in the row, but not if you press in the checkbox.

Thanks in advance

```
public class MyClass extends HmBaseActivity{

    protected ListView listView ;
    protected CheckBox selectDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play_all_day);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.weekList);
        listView.setChoiceMode(listView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        selectDay = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_play_all_day);

       final String[] values = new String[] {
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday",
                "Sunday"};

        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_days, R.id.play_all_day, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + position + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
selectDay.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButtonView, boolean isChecked) {

     // ListView Clicked item value
        String  itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :" + position + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
   });
```

Comment: It's a different issue, just debug your app and check why selectDay is null